# WPF wrappanel how to pass data to a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

Im not 100% this goes with the whole wpf mvvm design pattern but I'm lost on how to do it.

I have a main view in this main view i have ObservableCollection called 'DemoClass_List', each element in the list contains a class 'DemoClass'.

In the wpf for this view i have wrappanel, what i want is for the wrappanel to display a usercontrol for each element, but also to pass the individual class to the element.

Code is below.

```
***UserControl
public partial class DemoClass_Display : UserControl
{
    public DemoClass _demoClass;

    public DemoClass_Display()
    {
        InitialiseComponent();
        //Do processing on _demoClass and display relevant info
    }
}

***MainView WPF Snippet
<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding DemoClass_List}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <usercontrol:DemoClass_Display/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The question is, how do i fill the item "public DemoClass _demoClass;" in the usercontrol?

****************Edit****************
This code crashes

****MainView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<DemoClass> DemoClass_List { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            DemoClass_List = new ObservableCollection<DemoClass>();
            DemoClass dc1 = new DemoClass();
            dc1.Property1 = 1;
            dc1.Property2 = 1;
            dc1.Property3 = 1;

           DemoClass dc2 = new DemoClass();
           dc2.Property1 = 2;
           dc2.Property2 = 2;
           dc2.Property3 = 2;

           DemoClass dc3 = new DemoClass();
           dc3.Property1 = 3;
           dc3.Property2 = 3;
           dc3.Property3 = 3;

           DemoClass_List.Add(dc1);
           DemoClass_List.Add(dc2);
           DemoClass_List.Add(dc3);



           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
}
```

***MainViewWPF

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DemoClass_List}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl:DemoClass_Display demoClass="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***UserControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DemoClass_Display.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DemoClass_Display : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DemoClassProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("demoClass", typeof (DemoClass), typeof (DemoClass_Display), new PropertyMetadata(default(DemoClass)));

        public DemoClass demoClass
        {
            get { return (DemoClass)GetValue(DemoClassProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DemoClassProperty, value); }
        }

        public DemoClass_Display()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine(demoClass.Property1);
        }
    }
}
```

The console crashes as demoClass hasnt been set

Comment: Updated the answer. Added a propertychanged handler. Access the property inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a dependency property in your `UserControl`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DemoClassProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DemoClass", typeof (DemoClass), typeof (DemoClass_Display), new PropertyMetadata(default(DemoClass), OnDemoClassChanged));

public DemoClass DemoClass
{
    get { return (DemoClass) GetValue(DemoClassProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DemoClassProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnDemoClassChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newDemoClass = e.NewValue as DemoClass;
    var demoClassDisplay = (DemoClass_Display)dependencyObject; // you can access this UserControl this way.       

    if(newDemoClass != null)
    {
        //Do processing on newDemoClass and display relevant info
    }
}
```

And then you can bind the current item of the `ItemsControl` in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <usercontrol:DemoClass_Display DemoClass="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

So inside the `UserControl` you will use the `DemoClass` property instead of the field `_demoClass`. I think that can even be deleted.

Comment: Almost correct. But dependency property should be declared with propertychanged handler in order to have ability to process data when it is bound.

Comment: Thanks, noted and added to the answer.

Comment: Processing can't be done directly in static function.
I guess, it may be not obviuos that it's necessary to cast dependencyObject to  DemoClass_Display and apply all processing to casted reference.

Comment: He can access the old and new value of the property. Also he can access the `UserControl` as well (`(DemoClass_Display)dependencyObject`). I don't see the problem....

Comment: that all works exactly how i want (well apart from a binding issue but think that qualifies as a new question. If i could vote up the above answer i would

Comment: @nicolay.anykienko The PropertyChangedCallback would only be necessary when there is actually something to do in it. Often, you don't need it at all because the UserControl's XAML has "internal" bindings to its own property.

Comment: @Clemens, yes, sure. It depends on how property is used